# Convert php array_sum to java

Tags: java, php

```
$a = array(2, 4, 6, 8);
echo "sum(a) = " . array_sum($a) . "\n";  //==20
```

how i can do this in java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    long array_sum(int...array)
    {
        long sum = 0;
        for(int value : array)
            sum += value;
        return sum;
    }
```

**Example:**

```
System.out.println(array_sum(1, 2, 3, -1));
System.out.println(array_sum(1, 2));
System.out.println(array_sum(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}));

5
3
15
```

Comment: The warning is not needed. i.e. (long) Integer.MAX_VALUE (the largest value) * Integer.MAX_VALUE (the largest array you can have) < Long.MAX_VALUE

Comment: @Peter, I suppose that applies for underflow aswell? I'll edit it right away.

Comment: the biggest negative number is larger but still with Long.MIN_VALUE (basically using long for the sum is the right solution ;)

Comment: @Peter, Thanks. Didn't realize that until today... :)

Answer (score 0):

Google search says, "No". Is it not possible to loop through the array and find the sum?

Comment: There is no JRE API method - but that doesn't stop experts to implement a short `array_sum` equivalent in Java :)